# Can you enforce a schema on Excel files before appending in PowerBI?

Tags: excel, azure, powerbi

Is there a way of validating the file structure (column format/schema) of an Excel sheet before importing it into PowerBI?

Consider the below scenario for validation:

Excel files 1,2, and 3 are to be appended into file 4, these have the following columns:

```
Schema: ID | FullName | DoB

E.g. 1)

File 1: ID | FullName | DoB 
File 2: ID | FullName | DoB 
File 3: ID | VehicleRegNo | DoB 

E.g. 2)

File 1: ID | FullName | DoB 
File 2: ID | FullName | DoB 
File 3: ID | FullName | DoB | VehicleRegNo 

E.g. 3)

File 1: ID | FullName | DoB 
File 2: ID | FullName | DoB 
File 3: ID 

Required: The user will be prompted with an error since Files 1,2 and 3 do not have the same schema ('columns').
```

The validation on the Excel sheet is required to ensure that when different files are appended from different excel sheets that an error would prompt the user if there are any differences in the input sheets.

Tried looking into Azure Data Factory but this is done against a fee. Is there any other way/product to validate the file structure?